# Twilio PHP Quick Start help.. Not finding the AutoLoad.php file or not loading it

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to use the Twilio PHP Quick Start and I think have followed all of the instructions. I get the following errors when I enter this at the command line :
Williams2017MBP:~ williambrown$ php ~/Sites/send_sms.php

Warning: require_once(/vendor/twilio/sdk/scr/Twilio/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/williambrown/Sites/send_sms.php on line 2

Call Stack:
    0.0028     394160   1. {main}() /Users/williambrown/Sites/send_sms.php:0

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/vendor/twilio/sdk/scr/Twilio/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.17_1/share/php@7.3/pear') in /Users/williambrown/Sites/send_sms.php on line 2

Call Stack:
    0.0028     394160   1. {main}() /Users/williambrown/Sites/send_sms.php:0

Here is my Code:

---

```
<?php
require_once '/vendor/twilio/sdk/scr/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$account_sid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$auth_token = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
// I have added the actual $account_sid and $auth_token. 
//I am just not displaying the here:

// A Twilio number you own with SMS capabilities
$twilio_number = "+19999999999";

$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
$client->messages->create(
    // Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
    '+18888888888',
    array(
        'from' => $twilio_number,
        'body' => 'Hey I sent this message in under 10 minutes!'
    )
);
?>
```

I am on a MacBook Pro. I have installed PHP 7.3.17, the Twilio php helper library, HomeBrew, Apache and Composer.

Comment: require  '/vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: yes I tried that and it throw and error -- "no file, can't open stream"

Comment: have you ran composer update?

Comment: Here's an update: The phone number wasn't active and the same for the credentials. I have the issue working now.